# Use Spring Data DAL with grails (or other web framework)

Tags: java, grails, spring-data

I've created a "framework/toolkit" for a specific type of database search. This was done with Spring-Data JPA using hibernate. This framework is usable by standalone desktop app or as a web application.

This framework ships with entity classes, Spring-Data Repositories and a transactional Service layer with optional method level security (spring-security annotations).

now I would like to create a web application using this framework. Since grails is from spring to and also uses hibernate I thought this might work but I'm open to other suggestions.

The entities in the web application will extend such provided by my framework and should use spring-data repositories extending repositories provided by the framework and services extending provided services for data access.

Or said otherwise I'm mainly interested in the scaffolding part (controller and CRUD web pages) and not the data access part. I'm open to any other tools that can achieve this.

Is this possible with grails? Other suggestions? Spring Roo?